# How can I tell if the logged in user has a certain permission?

Tags: permissions

How can I tell if the currently logged-in user has a certain permission in CiviCRM?

Should I use CMS-dependent functions, like [user_access('permission')](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7) in Drupal, or can I use one CiviCRM function to check the permission for the current user?

For example, how could I display a message if the currently logged-in user has the 'edit all contacts' permission?

Comment: Tell where? Template? Drupal module? CiviCRM extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
CRM_Core_Permission::check('edit all contacts')
```

Comment: Ugh, I forgot this, Googled it, found my own answer.  Wish I could upvote it! :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you've set the permissions, what ACL groups they're in or what roles you've given them in the CMS